# How do I get my node.js to work with my visual studio code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, error-handling

I can't get my node.js to work with my visual studio code terminal. I do have node.js installed but I can't create a react app. I don't know what is wrong, please help. I type in on the Visual Studio code terminal "npm create-react-app ecommerce-app" and get the following error:

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- npm create-react-app ecommerce-app
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npx:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Answer (score 0):

**I don't know what operating system you have here I'll assume you have windows 10 .**

### Let's go by steps

> First you have to install [Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) which comes with the npm dependency manager.
> Once installed check that these commands in a terminal return you something:

```sh
npm -v
# returns the version of npm installed
node -v
# sends you the version of nodejs installed
```

**If you have nothing restart your computer, then make sure that :**

You have a nodejs folder in

```sh
C:\Program Files\nodejs #(for the 64bits version)
C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs #(for the 32bits version)
```

**Then check if you have your Path variable nodejs**

Go to System Properties, then Environment variables and add in the section User variable:

```sh
# New -> 
variable name: Node 
value of the variable: C:\Program Files\nodejs #(for the 64bits version)
# is the path to your nodejs folder
```

Once this is done you should by typing the previous commands:

```sh
npm -v
node -v
# get the versions.
```

### Now you have 2 possibilities to create-react-app

**either you install it on your local machine by doing a**

```sh
npm i -g create-react-app
# this command will install (i) the creat-react-app package in global (-g) on your machine 
# and you can create a project with the command
reate-react-app ecommerce-app
```

**Or you can use the npx command which allows you not to install the package locally:**

```sh
npx create-react-app ecommerce-app
```

*Hoping that this will help you*

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work. I just got the same error but with npx instead of npm.

Comment: what is your OS ? windows ?