# trying to install next js on VS code but show error by saying npm not recognized

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js

I am trying to install next js in VS code, when I type 'npx create-next-app' in the powershell terminal in VS, it showed error by saying:

`The term 'npx' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I have already install node 10.13 like the documentation of next asked me to...

Here is a picture

[image]

Comment: do you specify the name of your app ? like "npx create-next-app my-app" or in current folder like "npx create-next-app ." check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426517/how-do-i-get-my-node-js-to-work-with-my-visual-studio-code/) to make sure everything is set up properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means npx is not installed in your machine please check or update your npm or installed npx first.

use this cmd to check if it is installed or not `npx --version` if not then update your node and npm version

as in your attachment, you did not pass the project name as you should provide the project name as well `npx create-next-app myapp`

Answer (score 0):

When installed, try

```
npx create-next-app [name here]

cd my-project
```

Answer (score 0):

Install node.js, helped me. Then check version. npx -v, then install it npx create-react-app my-app for example